# How to authenticate async event messaging between services in microservice architecture

Tags: authorization, microservices, messaging

If my services communicate over Sync HTTP I would pass the JWT token to each service so each service an authenticate the request and ensure it is only providing data for the authenticated user.

However, if I change my communication mechanism to using async messaging (e.g. RabbitMQ), how would I now authenticate the event to the scope of the user who initiated the event.  Should the same JWT be passed as part of the event message.  I see an issue with this mechanism, in that the JWT may have expired by time the service processes the message which means the message will not get processed.

Is this the general approach and best practice, or should some sort of trusted policy be created and passed as a alias to the original JWT stating what that user could do and had access to, or is there a different approach?

Comment: do you really need this JWT token to process the message after it is consumed from SQS? Can't you just limit the use of JWT to your entry-point, validate taken and then send rest of the data to further processing to the SQS?

Comment: whilst that is an option and one that is currently used in my application.  My application is a SaaS application which has multiple tenants and  a. I need to make sure that these tenants data never crosses and b. that access to the data is secure as possible e.g. someone cannot just manually place a message on an SQS queue that allows one tenant access to another tenants data.  If this were HTTP, I would just pass the same token around, hence my query about if there is a similar way within messaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the user invokes the first microservice you should trust the communication among your services, so you dont need a jwt or standard token. You can pass in the event some sort of identification of the original user or its scopes to ensure that the reciever service filter the information accordingly.

This identification can be even a jwt token without expiration because it will be a token that only is used internally among your services so there is no risk that a malicious user tamper it.

Comment: That was my thoughts.  I have been watching https://aws.amazon.com/partners/saas-factory/ and they state using the original JWT between service communication which works for synchronous calls.  The video talks about using policies to express what the user can do which is something that can be passed between services along with the message.  And this can be done along with a custom JWT for identification as in your answer.

Comment: An internal token without an expiration time is a very questionable approach, because if 1 service gets hacked then your entire system will be compromised.

Comment: It depends on the scenario you are in, if you are in a zero trust scenario where you cant trust in any other service, the effort and overload of the system will be increaswd of course.As always, all decisions implies a tradeoff

Comment: Is there a case when you are not in a zero trust scenario?  Aren't all systems susceptible to breach?  I feel it's safer, with low negative trade-off, to ensure that tokens are expired at the earliest practical time.